# JQuery selection not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am giving an id of "song-pick" in the following code.

```
$("#archive").append("<div id=\"song-pick\" data-song=\""+song.rank+"\" class=\"box small back"+counter+"\"><span>"+song.title+"</span></div>");
```

And trying to print by

```
$('#song-pick').on("click", function() {
  console.log("PICKED");
}
```

It gets the id well and I can see it on the web as:

```
<div id="song-pick" data-song="1" class="box small back1"><span>소녀 (A Little Girl) </span></div>
```

However if I click the element, it doesn't print anything on console.
I have no idea why. Tried to fix it by changing to li or ul tags instead of div tag but it didn't work. Need help.

Comment: It won't work if `$('#song-pick').on("click")` was called *before* the element was created. Make sure your ordering is correct, or, change it to `$(document).on("click", "#song-pick", callback)` to apply for all future elements.

Comment: You need event delegation method.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 `on` make a dynamic binding so order is not important ..corrrect me if im wrong

Comment: @coolguy Only when you do it the second way as in my comment.

Comment: **id will be duplicate.**

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 thanks man i didnt know that

Comment: Hello , please use  like this $(function () { $('#song-pick').on("click", function() {
  console.log("PICKED");
}  }

Comment: @Martin park ..you can use `on` or `delegate` for this ..there are plenty of examples in SO related to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#archive').on("click",'#song-pick', function() {
  console.log("PICKED");
});
```

Delegate through an element which is there in the DOM.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Note:** the way you append the song will produce duplicate `ID`. and **`ID` should always be unique**